# UWP wabbrowser clear cache

Tags: c#, uwp, identity

I want to clear cache before opening my wabbrowser how can I do it? I am using Ad authentication and when giving username and password ppassword doesn't go to backend.
I used the following code in github for  my project https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/blob/main/Uwp/UwpSample/WabBrowser.cs

wabbrowser code

```
public class WabBrowser : IBrowser
{
    private readonly bool _enableWindowsAuthentication;

    public WabBrowser(bool enableWindowsAuthentication = false)
    {
        _enableWindowsAuthentication = enableWindowsAuthentication;
    }

    private async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsyncCore(BrowserOptions options, bool silentMode)
    {
        var wabOptions = WebAuthenticationOptions.None;

        if (_enableWindowsAuthentication)
        {
            wabOptions |= WebAuthenticationOptions.UseCorporateNetwork;
        }
        if (silentMode)
        {
            wabOptions |= WebAuthenticationOptions.SilentMode;
        }

        WebAuthenticationResult wabResult;

        try
        {
            if (string.Equals(options.EndUrl, WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl));
            }
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.EndUrl))
                {
                    wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl), WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri());
                }
                else
                {
                    wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl), new Uri(options.EndUrl));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.WriteErrorsToLogViaMessenger("WabBrowser-InvokeAsyncCore", ex);

            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UnknownError,
                Error = ex.ToString()
            };
        }

        if (wabResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success,
                Response = wabResult.ResponseData
            };
        }
        else if (wabResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.HttpError,
                Error = string.Concat(wabResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString())
            };
        }
        else if (wabResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel)
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UnknownError,
                Error = "Invalid response from WebAuthenticationBroker"
            };
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options)
    {
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.StartUrl)) throw new ArgumentException("Missing StartUrl", nameof(options));
        //if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.EndUrl)) throw new ArgumentException("Missing EndUrl", nameof(options))

        switch (options.DisplayMode)
        {
            case DisplayMode.Visible:
                return await InvokeAsyncCore(options, false);

            case DisplayMode.Hidden:
                var result = await InvokeAsyncCore(options, true);
                if (result.ResultType == BrowserResultType.Success)
                {
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.ResultType = BrowserResultType.Timeout;
                    return result;
                }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid DisplayMode", nameof(options));
    }

    public Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return InvokeAsync(options);
    }
}
```

Calling wabbrowser

```
 private static OidcClientOptions GetOidcOptions(bool isEnableWindowsAuthentication=false)
    {
        string logInfo = "OidcClient Options: RedirectUri: " + WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri;
        Utility.WriteErrorsToLogViaMessenger("IdentityManager-GetOidcOptions", new Exception(logInfo));

        string address = Utility.ReplaceLastOccurrence(Global.ServerUrlAuth, "/" + Global.Identifier, string.Empty).TrimEnd('/');
      
        return new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = address, 
            ClientId = "boardpac.openid.windows",
            Scope = ApplicationConstants.ScopeForIdentityManager 
            RedirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri,
            Browser = new WabBrowser(enableWindowsAuthentication: isEnableWindowsAuthentication),
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri,
        };
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean _Web-browser_ - not "_Wab_".

Comment: Are you running your own OIDC/OAuth2 IDP or using a hosted service (e.g. Otka, AAD/Entra, etc?). Also please share your OIDC/OAuth2 client configuration.

Comment: @Dai  we are using OAuth2

Comment: ...that doesn't tell me if you're running your own IDP or not.

Comment: `new Exception(logInfo));` <-- Don't do this...

Comment: @Dai we are using our own IDP

Comment: What do you mean by "_doesn't go to backend_"? How have you determined that? Have you looked at the raw HTTP traffic (e.g. using WireShark, CharlesProxy, or Fiddler?) or set a debugger breakpoint on your IDP's endpoint handlers?